# Comparing Two Enums for all possible cases

Tags: ios, swift, switch-statement

I have an enum with a bunch of different cases. Imagine it being like rock paper scissors.

```
enum Play {
    case Rock, Paper, Scissors
}
```

Now I am making a class that will have a `Play` property and a method that takes another `Play` parameter as the "Attacker" and I need to compare all possible outcomes. The only way I can think to do it would be nested switches but that becomes a massive function with a high chance of error since my enum has much more than 3 cases.

```
func determineEffectiveness(withAttacker attacker: Play) {
    switch attacker.type {
        case .Rock {
            switch self.type {
                case .Rock {
                    return 0
                }
                case .Paper {
                    return 1
                }
                case .Scissors {
                    return -1
                }
            }
        }
        case .Paper {
             // ...etc
        }
    }
}
```

This is an ugly brute force method but I'm struggling to come up with a better solution.

UPDATE:

As per usual... right after I ask the question I came up with a better solution. I am going to put that solution as an answer but I won't accept it until I get answers from others because there could be a better way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rock, Paper, Scissors is a parity game. It becomes a bit clearer if you make the game more complicated, like Rock, Paper, Scissors, Spock, Lizard. If the distance is even, then the lower value wins. If the distance is odd, then the higher values wins. Here's a simple way we could build that:

```
enum Hand: Int {
    enum Result {
        case lose, tie, win
    }

    case rock, paper, scissors, spock, lizzard

    func result(against: Hand) -> Result {
        let distance = rawValue - against.rawValue

        if distance == 0 { return .tie }

        if distance % 2 == 0 {
            return (rawValue < against.rawValue) ? .win : .lose
        }

        return (rawValue > against.rawValue) ? .win : .lose
    }
}
```

Of course this still works for R-P-S. Just drop the last two elements. Just keep in mind that the enum order is very important.

Comment: I have never looked at rock paper scissors in this way. This is fascinating. Unfortunately my game isn't really a rock paper scissors type scenario. There are multiple "effective" types. It's more like pokemon type effectiveness where fire is weak against both water and rock.

Comment: You should think about whether there is still a mathematical pattern in those strengths and weaknesses. If a game is well balanced, you would expect it to be built on stable patterns. Expressing the pattern may turn out be less flexible than you need, but it's definitely worth exploring. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I will look more into that path

Comment: I'm going to select this answer because I do feel like it is the best answer for the question asked. I haven't yet found a mathematical pattern for my use case but this does best answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

You could simply `switch` on a tuple of the `Play` instances to compare, using the `==` operator in order to determine whether they are equal, and a series of enum case pattern matches to define whether on play is more effective than another.

For example:

```
enum Play {

    case rock, paper, scissors

    enum Effectiveness {
        case effective, equal, notEffective
    }

    // You may want to consider not returning an Int, but instead
    // an enum that defines the Effectiveness of an attack (given that you
    // only ever return 3 values).
    func effectiveness(against attacker: Play) -> Effectiveness {
        switch (self, attacker) {

        // if the same case (binds self to x, and attacker to y, and then 
        // uses the equality operator to determine whether the case should be triggered).
        case let (x, y) where x == y:
            return .equal

        // if self beats attacker
        case (.paper, .rock), (.rock, .scissors), (.scissors, .paper):
            return .effective

        // else self doesn't beat attacker
        default: 
            return .notEffective
        }
    }
}

print(Play.paper.effectiveness(against: .rock)) // effective
print(Play.scissors.effectiveness(against: .rock)) // notEffective
print(Play.paper.effectiveness(against: .paper)) // equal
```

Comment: Can you further explain the `case let (x, y) where x == y`? I have never seen that syntax (I'm still new to swift but not programming). From what I can tell it's just saying the case where the two parts of the tuple are equal?

Comment: @CaldwellYSR Precisely – it's unconditionally binding `self` to `x` and `attacker` to `y`, and then performing an `==` comparison, which will determine if the case is triggered or not. I'll add an inline comment to my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the Play type should provide the means of "comparing itself" to others. And in the end makes things much easier and clearer:

```
enum Play {
    case rock, paper, scissors
    enum PlayResult {
        case aBeatsB, bBeatsA, tie
    }
    func beats(_ other: Play) -> Bool {
        switch (self, other) {
        case (.rock, .scissors):
            return true
        case (.scissors, .paper):
            return true
        case (.paper, .rock):
            return true
        default:
            // other cases are either ties or loses
            return false
        }
    }
    func resultOfGame(against other: Play) -> PlayResult {
        if (self.beats(other)) {
            return .aBeatsB
        } else if (other.beats(self)) {
            return .bBeatsA
        } else {
            return .tie
        }
    }
}

func printGame(_ a: Play, against b: Play) {
    switch a.resultOfGame(against: b) {
    case .aBeatsB:
        print("\(a) beats \(b)")
    case .bBeatsA:
        print("\(b) beats \(a)")
    case .tie:
        print("\(a) vs. \(b) is a tie")
    }
}

printGame(.rock, against: .scissors)
printGame(.paper, against: .paper)
```

outputs:

> rock beats scissors
>
> paper vs. paper is a tie

Comment: Oh that makes sense. It also fits the separation of concerns. I had no idea you could switch on a tuple like that either. I'm still not sure about the switch statement though because my rock paper scissors enum has 10 or 15 cases right now.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this solution that would be much cleaner but I'm not going to accept it at first. I want to see if there is another, better method that I am not thinking of.

It might be a better solution to create arrays for the possible advantages and then make an exhaustive switch in my initializer like so:

```
var strongAgainst: [Play]
var weakAgainst: [Play]

init(withPlayType play: Play) {
    switch play {
        case .Rock {
            strongAgainst.append(Play.Scissors)
            weakAgainst.append(Play.Paper)
            break
        }
        // ...etc
    }
}
```

This would make my attack method simpler by letting my check if the attacking type is in the `strongAgainst` or `weakAgainst` arrays.

Comment: Given how you've described your deeper problem, this is probably the best solution, except I would define all the relationships in a single data structure (probably a dictionary). It's definitely the most flexible approach if your graph lacks a simple pattern.